# How to use GPU while training XGBoost model?

Tags: python, gpu, xgboost

I have been trying to train a XGBoost model in a Jupyter Notebook. I installed XGboost(GPU) by following commands:

```
git clone — recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DUSE_CUDA=ON
make -j
```

But whenever I try to train the model but `model.fit`, the kernel restarts after a few minutes.
code:

```
params = { 'max_depth': 50, 'n_estimators':80, 'learning_rate':0.1, 'colsample_bytree':7, 'gamma':0, 'reg_alpha':4, 'objective':'binary:logistic', 'eta':0.3, 'silent':1, 'subsample':0.8, 'tree_method':'gpu_hist', 'predictor':'gpu_predictor',}
xgb_model = xgb.XGBClassifier(**params).fit(X_train, y_train) 
xgb_prediction = xgb_model.predict(X_valid)
```

where X_train and y_train are derived form sklearn `TfidfVectorizer`

I have cuda installed,
`cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt` gives : `CUDA Version 10.2.89`

Comment: Hi @ent3r_, Python 3.7.6

Answer (score 4):

Try using `param['updater'] = 'grow_gpu'` as another parameter with XGBClassifier. Read this in detail here: https://xgboost.ai/2016/12/14/GPU-accelerated-xgboost.html.

Comment: currently is `grow_gpu_hist`

Comment: use tree_method="gpu_hist"